# How to correctly configure .ASPXAUTH

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, forms-authentication

We have a **.NET MVC 4** site which is hosted in **IIS 7**. We have configured to have a secure authentication cookie. We need the login to be secure over SSL.

In the web config we have put

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="2880" requireSSL="true" domain="domain.com"/>
</authentication>
```

And in the Login controller we have set the values for the authentication cookie

```
var authenticationTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, Email, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), false, userData);
string encrypt = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authenticationTicket);
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encrypt)
{
    HttpOnly = true,
    Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL,
    Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath,
    Domain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain
});
```

But when you try to login the cookie shows as secure but user cannot login; site redirects back to the login page (HTTP 302 found).

**Question:** How do we configure this correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you creating your ticket?  Please include that code.

Comment: I just added the code of creating the authentication ticket.